# Programmatically infer schema to prepare spark dataframe Dataset<Row> from RDD<Row> when some Row objects may contain different number of elements

Tags: java, apache-spark, neo4j

I am fetching neo4j node information in spark rdd using [neo4j-spark connector](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-spark-connector). I can obtain `RDD<Row>` by calling [`loadNodeRdds()` method](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-spark-connector/blob/master/src/main/scala/org/neo4j/spark/Neo4j.scala#L236). But when I try obtaining dataframe calling [`loadDataframe()` method](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-spark-connector/blob/master/src/main/scala/org/neo4j/spark/Neo4j.scala#L344), it throws exception (skip stack trace if you find it too long as main question might turn out to be different in the end):

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error while encoding: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableMap is not a valid external type for schema of string
if (assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true], top level row object).isNullAt) null else staticinvoke(class org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String, StringType, fromString, validateexternaltype(getexternalrowfield(assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true], top level row object), 0, Condition), StringType), true) AS Condition#4
+- if (assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true], top level row object).isNullAt) null else staticinvoke(class org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String, StringType, fromString, validateexternaltype(getexternalrowfield(assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true], top level row object), 0, Condition), StringType), true)
   :- assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true], top level row object).isNullAt
   :  :- assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true], top level row object)
   :  :  +- input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true]
   :  +- 0
   :- null
   +- staticinvoke(class org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String, StringType, fromString, validateexternaltype(getexternalrowfield(assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true], top level row object), 0, Condition), StringType), true)
      +- validateexternaltype(getexternalrowfield(assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true], top level row object), 0, Condition), StringType)
         +- getexternalrowfield(assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true], top level row object), 0, Condition)
            +- assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true], top level row object)
               +- input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true]

(skipped a lot of rows as it made question reach its character limit)
```

I was not able to get much from big stackrace above.

So I took `JavaRDD<Row>` and tried converting it to `DataFrame<Row>` by programmatically specifying [`StructType` schema](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/sql-programming-guide.html#programmatically-specifying-the-schema).

```
StructType schema = loadSchema();
Dataset<Row> df = ss.createDataFrame(neo4jJavaRdd , schema);
```

This threw somewhat similar exception.

So what I did is that I took individual properties of single neo4j node, prepared `Row` and then `JavaRDD<Row>` from it and then tried to create dataframe from it by programatically specifying schema as follows:

```
Row row1 = RowFactory.create("val1", " val2", "val3", "val4", "val5", "val6", 152214d, "val7", 152206d, 11160d, "val8");
List<StructField> fields = new ArrayList<StructField>();
fields.add(DataTypes.createStructField("attr1", DataTypes.StringType, true));
fields.add(DataTypes.createStructField("attr2", DataTypes.StringType, true));
fields.add(DataTypes.createStructField("attr3", DataTypes.StringType, true));
fields.add(DataTypes.createStructField("attr4", DataTypes.StringType, true));
fields.add(DataTypes.createStructField("attr5", DataTypes.StringType, true));
fields.add(DataTypes.createStructField("attr6", DataTypes.StringType, true));
fields.add(DataTypes.createStructField("attrd1", DataTypes.DoubleType, true));
fields.add(DataTypes.createStructField("attr7", DataTypes.StringType, true));
fields.add(DataTypes.createStructField("attrd2", DataTypes.DoubleType, true));
fields.add(DataTypes.createStructField("attrd3", DataTypes.DoubleType, true));
fields.add(DataTypes.createStructField("attr8", DataTypes.StringType, true));
```

This worked.

So I checked all nodes and realized that not all nodes (that is all `Row`s in `JavaRDD<Row>`) have same number of attributes. This is must be causing data frame preparation to fail. Can I handle it some way programatically without requiring to [create and specify pojo](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/sql-programming-guide.html#inferring-the-schema-using-reflection).

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to get this done using RDDs as you mentioned, do as follows:

- Before trying to transform the (RDD + schema) to a dataframe,
  go over the RDD (using the map function), and make sure each row has all the relevant attributes.
- If an attribute is not present in a row, add it and make it null.

After that, your RDD rows will have the same schema, and the transformation to a dataframe will work.

Answer (score 0):

There are certain things that I came to realize while working with [neo4j-spark-connector](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-spark-connector) that I want to share here.

1. **In general, if you are going to prepare dataframe**, its not preferrable to return neo4j's object types, specifically node and relationship. That is something like below returning node is not preferrable:

   ```
   MATCH(n {id:'xyz'}) RETURN n
   ```

   Instead return properties:

   ```
   MATCH(n {id:'xyz'}) RETURN properties(n)
   ```
2. **If you are unsure that all nodes will not have same number of properties**, then its better to return them explicitly, instead of returning properties and obtaining JavaRDD. Since that will require us to process `JavaRDD` again to add `NULL` for non existent properties. That, is instead of doing this:

   ```
   MATCH(n {id:'xyz'}) RETURN properties(n)
   ```

   return in this way:

   ```
   MATCH(n {id:'xyz'}) RETURN n.prop1 AS prop1, n.prop2 AS prop2, ..., n.propN AS propN
   ```

   Neo4j will itself add `NULL`s for non existing properties as it can be seen image below, we dont have to iterate over them again. By returning this, I was able to obtain neo4j node information directly by using `loadDataframe()` method.

   [image]