# Join of two dataframes was working but now it fails when I changed content of one of the dataframes

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, neo4j

I was doing following:

- fetching dataframe from neo4j using neo4j-spark-connector
- fetching dataframe from hbase using apache hbase spark connector
- printing both dataframe to console by `df.show()`
- joining both data frames using spark sql using unique id column present in both dataframes:

  ```
  Dataset<Row> mergedData = ss.sql("SELECT * from hbasetable, neo4jtable WHERE hbasetable.nodeId = neo4jtable.id");
  ```
- printing joined dataframe to console by `mergedData.show()`

This was working perfectly fine. However, now, I changed the cypher query using which I was fetching neo4j data. Earlier my cypher used to like this:

```
Match (n:Type1 {caption:'type1caption"'})-[:contains]->(m:Type2) return m.attr1, m.attr2, m.attr3, m.attr4, m.attr5, m.attr6, m.attr7, m.attr8, m.id as id, m.attr9, m.attr10, m.attr11
```

Now its like this:

```
Match (m:Type1) return m.attr1, m.attr2, m.attr3, m.attr4, m.attr5, m.attr6, m.attr7, m.attr8, m.id as id, m.attr9, m.attr10, m.attr11
```

But now the joining fails. It gives me following exception:

```
Long is not a valid external type for schema of string
```

It seems that the contents of both new neo4j dataframe and hbase dataframe are getting correctly fetched as both `neo4jdf.show()` and `hbasedf.show()` shows data on console. I was wondering, if earlier join was working fine and if data is getting correctly fetched, then what can fail the join.

Main concern is that I am unable to interpret the stack trace printed on the console. It looks something like this:

```
18/06/04 17:47:48 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 4.0 (TID 4)
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error while encoding: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.Long is not a valid external type for schema of string
if (assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true], top level row object).isNullAt) null else validateexternaltype(getexternalrowfield(assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true], top level row object), 0, m.attr1), NullType) AS m.attr1#0
+- if (assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true], top level row object).isNullAt) null else validateexternaltype(getexternalrowfield(assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true], top level row object), 0, m.attr1), NullType)
   :- assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true], top level row object).isNullAt
   :  :- assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true], top level row object)
   :  :  +- input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true]
   :  +- 0
   :- null
   +- validateexternaltype(getexternalrowfield(assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true], top level row object), 0, m.attr1), NullType)
      +- getexternalrowfield(assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true], top level row object), 0, m.attr1)
         +- assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true], top level row object)
            +- input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true]

     :
     :
   lot of stack trace omitted
     :
     :
if (assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true], top level row object).isNullAt) null else staticinvoke(class org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String, StringType, fromString, validateexternaltype(getexternalrowfield(assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true], top level row object), 11, m.attr11), StringType), true) AS m.attr11#11
+- if (assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true], top level row object).isNullAt) null else staticinvoke(class org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String, StringType, fromString, validateexternaltype(getexternalrowfield(assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true], top level row object), 11, m.attr11), StringType), true)
   :- assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true], top level row object).isNullAt
   :  :- assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true], top level row object)
   :  :  +- input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true]
   :  +- 11
   :- null
   +- staticinvoke(class org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String, StringType, fromString, validateexternaltype(getexternalrowfield(assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true], top level row object), 11, m.attr11), StringType), true)
      +- validateexternaltype(getexternalrowfield(assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true], top level row object), 11, m.attr11), StringType)
         +- getexternalrowfield(assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true], top level row object), 11, m.attr11)
            +- assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true], top level row object)
               +- input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true]

    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.ExpressionEncoder.toRow(ExpressionEncoder.scala:279)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$$anonfun$5.apply(SparkSession.scala:537)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$$anonfun$5.apply(SparkSession.scala:537)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:370)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:370)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$8$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:370)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:369)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.write(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:147)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:79)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:85)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:274)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.Long is not a valid external type for schema of string
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$SpecificUnsafeProjection.apply(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.ExpressionEncoder.toRow(ExpressionEncoder.scala:276)
    ... 16 more
```

The full stack trace can be found in [gist here](https://gist.github.com/Mahesha999/c284458d51141884fbff6f9415570d11)

I feel that this must be something related to inconsistency in neo4j data. If I can know the id of the neo4j node at which the exception is occurring I can check it. But I am absolutely not able to interpret this stacktrace. **Is it possible to know on which record preparation of dataframe is failed while performing join?**

**Update**

I removed everything related to join and hbase and added `neo4jdf.show(24000,false);`, and its giving the same error as above. There are 23748 records. When I print small number of records (say `neo4jdf.show(1000)`) it prints them without error. But, when I allow printing 24000 records, it fails. It means something is wrong with some node. But how can I pin point it?

Comment: "It seems that the contents of both new neo4j dataframe and hbase dataframe are getting correctly fetched as both neo4jdf.show() and hbasedf.show()" - it means that Spark is able to process 20 records from each, not that it can process full dataset. Based on error looks like one of stores contains inconsistent types - nothing related to join here.

Comment: I just edited the question to add stack trace at the end. I also tried to print 2000 records from neo4j. It printed all well without exception. Should I try printing all by giving some big number `x` in `neo4jdf.show(x)`? Say 100000? Also is this related to inconsistent type of data in some neo4j node attributes? if yes, how do I pin point it?

Comment: Couple of things. 1) your **new** cypher query can not possible be right as you have a variable **n** but get **m** properties. 2) to check if all id's are strings, try this query **MATCH (n:Type1) WHERE toString(n.id) <> n.id RETURN n.id;**

Comment: @TomGeudens 1) sorry that was a typo 2) Tried that query, returns no records. Point is whether the issue has to be with the id? or can it be with any other attribute? user8371915 "one of stores contains inconsistent types", can we pin point it in some definitive way?

Comment: @Mahesha999 ... well, I assumed it would have been the id as that is what you are doing the join on. Another possibility is that one of the *:Type1* nodes does actually not have one of these properties you want from it (as you know Neo4j typically does not use null, the node just does not have the property). You can check that with the **NOT EXISTS (n.<the property you are checking>)** clause.

Comment: But Neo4j will return `NULL` for non existent properties, right? Since I was returning each attribute excplicitly (that is, `return m.attr1, m.attr2, m.attr3, m.attr4, m.attr5...`), instead of doing `return properties(m)`) as can be seen in [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xM1U2.png). In fact, I gave [related answer recently on my own question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50675331/1317018).

Answer (score 0):

The source of the problem is heterogeneous data in your data source. Spark SQL uses relational model and no heterogenous columns are allowed.

If you cannot guarantee that all records are properly structured, I would advise fetching everything as string:

```
return toString(m.attr1), toString(m.attr2), ..., toString(m.attr11)
```

and cast back to the required types, using standard Spark operators:

```
df.select($"attr1".cast(...), ...)
```